# Resource identifier error while using org.panel package

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adt

I am trying to use org.panel package to implement a top down sliding drawer in android. However I get a few errors.

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'linearFlying' in package 'org.panel'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'position' in package 'org.panel'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'closedHandle' in package 
 'org.panel'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'animationDuration' in package 
 'org.panel'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'openedHandle' in package 
 'org.panel'
```

Here's the xml code that I found and am trying to run:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.panel"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.panel.Panel
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        panel:position="top"
        panel:animationDuration="1000"
        panel:linearFlying="true"
        panel:openedHandle="@drawable/ribbon"
        panel:closedHandle="@drawable/ribbon">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/panelHandle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="33dip" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelContent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="From the Top -> Down"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:padding="4dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ribbon"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </org.panel.Panel>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

How do I get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.panel
```

to

```
xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/src/org.panel
```

It's a change of `res` to `src`.

Answer (score 0):

## Images resources?

I didn't find reference to those names in your XML.

> **Those look like image names.**

Have you used Upper case in image names or other resource files (in res directory). The characters used could be one of **`[a-z1-9_]`**

Comment: No they aren't image names. They are attributes in XML

Comment: Oops! my bad, let me take a look again.